# CURAND undefined reference error

Tags: eclipse, cuda, nsight

I have pretty much the same problem as discussed in this question:

[CURAND Library - Compiling Error - Undefined reference to functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734578/curand-library-compiling-error-undefined-reference-to-functions)

Namely, after having included cuda.h, curand.h and curand_kernel libraries, using

```
    curandGenerator_t gen;
```

and

```
    curandCreateGenerator(&gen, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT);
```

gives me the following error:

```
    undefined reference to `curandCreateGenerator'
```

I am aware that this is a duplicate, but I really don't understand what should I do.

I'm using Nsight Eclipse on Ubuntu and I tried adding "**-lcurand** " to

*Project Properties -> Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> NVCC Compiler -> Command*

and I tried changing it to "**nvcc -o RNG7 RNG7.cu -lcurand -Xlinker=-rpath,/usr/local/cuda/lib**" as suggested, but nothing seems to work.

I'm a real newbie here, so a little detailed help would be appreciated, along with some reasons behind it, I prefer understanding things to quick fixes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, it was a very easy fix!

You need to go to:

*Project Properties -> Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> NVCC Linker -> Libraries*

and simply add a new library called "**curand"**.