# Function like rand(), to generate random number in CUDA _global_ kernel?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, random-seed

I am trying to create a Random generator for initialization of a vector.

The kernel function that I wrote in CUDA is as below:

```
__global__ void randgenvec( int *a, int t) {
    int tid = blockIdx.x; // handle the data at this index
    if (tid < t){
        a[tid] = rand() % 100; //****ang replacement for rand() here expect cuRAND?*****
    }
}
```

I got to know that I cant use `rand()` function inside a kernel function. Is there any other function which I can replace with `rand()`.

I know we have cuRAND library which we can use. But want to make my code more portable and light and cuRAND needs linker for execution, which I don't want to use.

The objective of my randomisation is to generate any int between 1 to 100.

> [By linker, I mean :: linker flag -lcurand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734578/curand-library-compiling-error-undefined-reference-to-functions)

Any other suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean you need linker for execution? If you're using CUDA, you're already linking Nvidia libraries and drivers in your project.

Comment: Hi @Kaldrr, By linker I mean - `linker flag -lcurand`. I have edited my question more clearly.

Comment: Please do not vote to reopen this. The linked duplicate is a good answer

Answer (score -2):

attempt this

```
 unsigned short lfsr = 0xACE1u;
  unsigned bit;

  unsigned randomize()
  {
    bit  = ((lfsr >> 0) ^ (lfsr >> 2) ^ (lfsr >> 3) ^ (lfsr >> 5) ) & 1;
    return lfsr =  (lfsr >> 1) | (bit << 15);
  }
```

Comment: Hi @MaslovKk, thanks for your answer. I am looking to generate numbers between 1 to 100. will code work if I do `randomize()%100` ?

Comment: No, don't attempt this. It isn't thread safe and won't work correctly in a massively parallel environment like CUDA, which it the question

Comment: @talonmies, can you suggest me some other functions I can use for randomization?

Comment: Yes. Use curand. High quality random numbers are difficult to get right. Doubly so in parallel. Use the library designed for the purpose. Your rationale for not doing so makes no sense

Comment: Okay I have decided to use cuRAND, but I am not able to figureout how to generate random numbers between 0 and 100 with cuRAND.